# Newbie in Machine Learning, need a strategy

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning

I am new to machine learning. However, I've some experience with python.

My question would be kind of "what should I do", sorry for that.

Basically, I have a project, and I want to use machine learning there.

I can represent the idea like this:

[image]

The blue box (Design) has up to 15 parameters which can be changed, and each parameter has up to 100 possible solutions (test cases), in total more than billion possible solutions for the design.

A Machine Learning (ML) algorithm proposed a parameter set for the design box, a checker (green box) checks if it meets the specifications.

Questions:

1. What do you recommend to understand/read/watch before to proceed to the problem?
2. What would you do if you have the same task as I? Which Libraries (Tensorflow, etc.) would you use? (your strategy)
3. Do you know any existed solutions?

Feedback, ideas, tips, hints are always welcome!

Comment: To get a computer to do what you want, its helpful to describe how you would solve the problem.then one can think about automating the process.

Answer (score 1):

The term machine learning targets a box of methods and approaches which do different things. 
The place to start with are two questions, which are connected:

- What do I want?  (such as Clustering, Regression, Classification)

Do you wish to estimate a target property such as a class of an image (house or human) or how much another customer will like a new movie x (such as netflix does) ? You can check [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) both for pratice datasets as well as for real applications and competitions in machine learning.

- What do I have? (Supervised vs Unsupervised Learning)

What you want to do is restricted by what you have. If you have labels or target variables, you can use methods from supervised learning, whereas otherwise you will use methods from unsupervised learning. Yet in most real applications you will probably combine both such as dimensionality reduction as a first step using PCA (unsupervised) and then classification (supervised).

As long as you are not familiar with these keywords (which are very basic, there is more to know later), you might want to read a great introduction into the topic: "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" by Bishop, which is available online as [pdf](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf)

Regarding libraries: Specifically for python there is a great library: [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/). This library does also contain a lot of examples and explanation in its documentation, yet I do recommend to actually read (parts of) the book by Bishop first.

Regarding your specific problem, you will have to break it down and translate it to terms of statistics and machine learning, enabling you to use the existing methods. There are no premade solutions, but rather exisiting libraries which provide implementations of most relevant algorithms which you will want to combine to create your own application/solution.